# Как по клику на элемент достучаться до дива с классом?

Tags: javascript

Как по клику на элемент `<i>` достучаться до дива с классом `faq-popup`?

```js
$('.btn-add-button').on('click', 'i', function(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  $(target).toggleClass('material-icons-remove');
  $(target).toggleClass('material-icons-add');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4">

  <div class="faq-wrap">

    <h3>Tempor Insididunt</h3>

    <div class="faq-popup hidePopup">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-add-button">
      <i class="material-icons-add"></i>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <h3>Tempor Insididunt</h3>
  <div class="faq-popup hidePopup">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-add-button">
    <i class="material-icons-add"></i>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <h3>Tempor Insididunt</h3>
  <div class="faq-popup hidePopup">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-add-button">
    <i class="material-icons-add"></i>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно достучаться так:

```
$('i').click(function() {
     var element = $(this).parent().parent().find('.faq-popup');
});
```

или так:

```
$('i').click(function() {
     var element = $(this).parent().prev('.faq-popup');
});
```

---

Как правильно заметил один из участников в ответе- это довольно плохой метод, так как при изменении структуры вам придется переписывать код доступа к элементу.
Я бы посоветовал вам после `<div class="col-md-4">` сделать еще один класс контейнер.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="container-item">
        <h3>Tempor Insididunt</h3>
        <div class="faq-popup hidePopup">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-add-button">
            <i class="material-icons-add"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

И поиск в этом случае производить так:

```
$('i').click(function() {
     var element = $(this).closest('.container-item').find('.faq-popup');
});
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное доступно!!

Comment: @climberDen Если вам помог какой-нибудь из ответов, вы можете отметить его как "принятый", установив зеленую галку под кнопками для голосования слева от ответа.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.btn-add-button').on('click','i',function(event) {
    $(event.currentTarget).closest('.col-md-4').find('faq-popup').hide();
});
```

Это не совсем хороший вариант, т. к. он завязан на класс, определяющий отображение контента, и, если кто-нибудь решит изменить количество колонок, код сломается.
В простейшем случае можно добавить какой-нибудь враппер, который будет объединять элементы.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('i').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('.col-md-4').find('.faq-popup').hide();   
});
```

В данном примере я скрываю `.faq-popup`, а ты уже добавишь какой тебе нужен функционал.

Метод `closest` - найдёт ближайшего родителя с классом `.col-md-4`. Потом методом `find`  в нём ищем `.faq-popup`.